# Why JVM frame need a reference to the run-time constant pool?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm reading [jvm documention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.3)

> Each frame (§2.6) contains a reference to the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) for the type of the current method to support dynamic linking of the method code. The class file code for a method refers to methods to be invoked and variables to be accessed via symbolic references.

But about them, at *2.6. Frames*:

> Only one frame, the frame for the executing method, is active at any point in a given thread of control. This frame is referred to as the current frame, and its method is known as the current method. The class in which the current method is defined is the current class. Operations on local variables and the operand stack are typically with reference to the current frame.

In *2.6. Frames*, it says

> This frame is referred to as the current frame, and its method is known as the current method. The class in which the current method is defined is the current class.

So, we already have a *current class* in a thread. Why do we need additional references to classes?

The key is dynamic linking? I'm a bit fuzzy.

Comment: What's the point of repeating part of the second quote as a third quote?

Comment: The second (and hence third) quote simply talks about *terminology* ("is referred to as" = "is known as" = "is called"): *"This frame **is called** the 'current frame', and its method **is called** the 'current method'. The class in which the current method is defined **is called** the 'current class'."*. --- The only *pointer* (reference) mentioned in all of that quoted text, is the pointer from the frame to the constant pool of the class. What additional pointers are you asking about?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks!!!

I'm just curious, we already have *'current class'* (if there's a place to keep this *'current class'* ), so it's actually possible to know which class the current frame is related to, and why we need the frame to refer to it.

That is: the reference in the frame is actually always to the *'current class'* (am I right?) which doesn't seem to be necessary. (We just need a place to keep track of *'current class'* and update it when the frame changes)

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: What do you mean by "we *already* have 'current class'"? Remember, if the method is `static`, there is no `this`, so we don't have that. So where would we be able to access the current class?

Comment: You say “we **already have** ‘current class’”, followed by “**if** there's a place to keep this ‘current class’” and “We **just need** a place to keep track of ‘current class’…”, in other words, you are subsequently admitting that this place does not (or might not) exist and has to be created, so you are assuming the existence of something you know to possibly not exist, to claim that a reference to the constant pool was unnecessary (“if” there was a reference to the current class).

Comment: You are right!! my question is really too nonsensical....